# SDL Events and Event Queues

Tags: c++, c, sdl-2

I want to make sure that I understand how SDL Events, Event Types and the Event Queue are handled internally.

An "SDL_Event" is essentially a union containing the data structures of all the event types.

And an event queue is a queue of these event unions.

1. Doesn't the event union contain a "type" member?(For ex, for an Event e we may access e.type to determine the type of event)
2. Since only a single union member can be accessed at a time(by the very definition of a union), how can the type AND the contents of the structure BOTH be accessed? (For ex, if e.type is SDL_QUIT, then the SDL_QuitEvent structure is accessed) How can the Union store both the type and contents of SDL_QuitEvent structure? What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

It uses a trick where all members of the SDL_Event union also have a member `Uint8 type;` as the first member, which is identical to `Uint8 type;`.

This works because there is no padding before them and they all share the same bytes and the same address:

Like this:

```
typedef struct 
{
    unsigned char type; 
    int other;
} keyboard;

typedef union
{
    unsigned char type;
    keyboard key;
} event;

event e;
assert( &e.type == &e.key.type );
```